# checking connection to server application

Tags: windows, tcp, network-programming, client-server, telnet

I have an application that is supposed to wait for a connection request from another program. In order to to so i received an API from the people who wrote the server application. When i use the API from my client application i get a connection failed message. Before i talk to the people in charge of the server and the API i want to check everything around it. I have access to the pc where the server is running but i don't have access to the servers code.

This is what i checked so far:

1. using "netstat -aonb" command on the server pc i saw that that the
   server process is listening on the port i am trying to connect.
2. using telnet on the servers ip and port i saw that there is a
   connection(got a blank screen)

is there anything else i can do?,is there a way on the server side to see if the request arrived/processed with no access to the code?

I'm have windows XP on the server and windows 7 on the client side

Thanks

Comment: Use a program such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)? Then you can capture the actual TCP packets to see if the connection request gets a proper response.

Comment: 'I get a connection failed message'. Only if that's what you printed yourself. It's not a TCP message. What was the actual errno/message/exception/stack trace? And if the message was provided by the server people, tell them it isn't adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions which are more into checking and trying different configurations.

1. both machines, check your DNS or the drivers/etc/hosts file if you're using hostnames instead of ip addresses.  Make sure the IPs are correct.
2. does your server program log any connection request or failure?  any server program specific configuration you missed?
3. if you have access, run your client program on the server box and connect to localhost instead.  If it works, this could be a bug in server program, or network related issue or some addressing issues.
4. on server box, check taskmanager and event viewer to see whether it's system/resource/memory issues instead of a connection problem
5. if all above fails, maybe you can try disabling windows firewall and antivirus on both machines.

That's all I can think of.  Hope these help.